# What's the correct way to construct my message handlers so that they can be moved out of the appHost?

Tags: c#, servicestack, rabbitmq

Given the following code for my RabbitMQ Request and Response messages:

```
public class AppHost : ServiceStackHost
{
    public AppHost()
        : base("LO.Leads.Processor", typeof(LeadService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //DataAccess

        //RabbitMQ
        container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer("cdev-9010.example.com", "test", "test") 
        {
            AutoReconnect = true,
            DisablePriorityQueues = true,

        }); 
        var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();
        var messageHandlers = new MessageHandlers(); // Is there a better way than newing up an instance?
        mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(messageHandlers.OnProcessLeadInformation, messageHandlers.OnExceptionLeadInformation);
        mqServer.Start();       
    }
}


public class MessageHandlers
{
    readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MessageHandlers));

    public object OnProcessLeadInformation(IMessage<LeadInformation> request)
    {

        _log.DebugFormat("Request message received {0}", request.Id);

        try
        {
            // Log to the database

            // Run rules against lead

            // Log response to database

            // return response

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(request, exception);
        }
        return new LeadInformationResponse();
    }

    public void OnExceptionLeadInformation(IMessage<LeadInformation> request, Exception exception)
    {
        _log.Error(request, exception);
    }

}
```

Most of the ServiceStack documentation shows examples where an anonymous method is used in-line, but that quickly bloats the apphost file and I'd like to move this code out closer to the service interface project. Is there anyway to define the delegate and not have to instantiate the "MessageHandlers" class?

**Updated May 29th, 2015**

Having had a few months to reflect on this question I wanted to add that I never implemented the changes to break out the method call from anonymous to delegate.

But now it's time to commit, and to that end I have come up with the 'template' class that matches the signature of the RegisterHandeler method, code below.

```
public static class HelloHandler
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("logger");

    public static Func<IMessage<ServiceModel.Hello>, object> ProcessMessageFn
    {
        get { return OnProcessMessage; }
    }

    public static Action<IMessageHandler, IMessage<ServiceModel.Hello>, Exception> ProcessExpectionFn
    {
        get { return OnProcessExpection; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static object OnProcessMessage(IMessage<ServiceModel.Hello> message)
    {

        return message;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handler"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    private static void OnProcessExpection(IMessageHandler handler, IMessage<ServiceModel.Hello> message, Exception exception)
    {
        /*
            public interface IMessageHandler
            {
                Type MessageType { get; }

                IMessageQueueClient MqClient { get; }

                void Process(IMessageQueueClient mqClient);

                int ProcessQueue(IMessageQueueClient mqClient, string queueName, Func<bool> doNext = null);

                void ProcessMessage(IMessageQueueClient mqClient, object mqResponse);

                IMessageHandlerStats GetStats();
            }
         */


        /*
            public interface IMessage<T> : IMessage, IHasId<Guid>
            {
                T GetBody();
            }
         */


        /*
            Exception
         */


    }
}
```

I'm leaning more towards this design to begin with, but that has me questioning the usage of the

> OnProcessExpection

method. What is the first parameter being passed in for? When would that be relevant and what can I do with it? The interface does have the GetStats method which might be beneficial in diagnosing and issue, but I'm just guessing.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: just make the methods static?

Comment: that's what I had done at first, but then do I need to be thread safe inside of the method? The answer is yes, right?

Comment: You should be threadsafe yes, but your instance method doesn't do anything to help with thread safety here because you're re-using the same instance. Although `ILog` is ThreadSafe.

Comment: @mythz I've updated the question to focus on the signature of the exception handler.

Comment: What's the question? the args in the error handler are just there in case your callback needs them.

Comment: @mythz I should have deleted the reply as I had found this response from you on another thread, and I asked the question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556641/ which summed up the parameters quite nicely.